# Solve for $a$ as a function of $\beta$?

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I am trying to solve this equation:

$$\beta^{-a} \Gamma(a) \sin(a \pi) + 
 e^\beta \beta^{2 a - 1} \Gamma(1 - a) \sin(a \pi) = 0$$

I tried the following:

```
Solve[β^-a Gamma[a] Sin[a π] + E^β β^(2 a - 1) Gamma[1 - a] Sin[a π] == 0, {a, β}]
```

However this is not working. Can you help me?

Answer (score 11):

First, this is a single equation in two unknowns so we'd expect infinitely many solutions.  So, let's try to solve for one variable in terms of the other:

```
Solve[β^-a Gamma[a] Sin[a π] + 
  E^β β^(2 a - 1) Gamma[1 - a] Sin[a π] == 
  0, β]
```

[image]

That message and the appearance of the `ProductLog` indicates that we simply might not be able to do much better.  If you try to solve for $a$, as you asked for, the empty list is returned; not surprising, as you've got an $a$ in an exponent, a $\sin$, and a $\Gamma$ function.

There certainly are solutions which we can see:

```
ContourPlot[E^β β^(-1 + 2 a)
 Gamma[1 - a] Sin[a π] + β^-a Gamma[a] Sin[a π] == 0,
 {a, -3, 3}, {β, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Using that image, we could certainly find good starting points for `FindRoot` to get good numerical values, if you like.

Comment: And `a == 0` OR `b == 0`

Comment: @belisarius The l.h.s. is undefined at all integral values of $a$, including $0$ (although it does have removable singularities there). It is not defined for $\beta=0$ because one or the other of the exponents $-a$ and $2a-1$ will be negative.

Comment: @whuber Yep. Thanks! I shouldn't try to do maths when I'm supposed to sleep :(

Answer (score 5):

A quick annotation:

I'm always sceptic when a weird function is spitted out by any mathematics program. With this in mind, I took the liberty to do the following analysis:

Suppose $a \not \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $\beta \neq 0$. Using [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties)

$$
\Gamma(a) \Gamma(1-a) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi a}
$$

is easy to see that

$$
\beta^{-a} \Gamma(a) \sin(a \pi) + 
 e^\beta \beta^{2 a - 1} \Gamma(1 - a) \sin(a \pi) = 0
$$

transforms into

$$
1 + \frac{\pi}{\Gamma^2(a)\sin (\pi a)}e^\beta \beta^{3a-1} = 0.
$$

Then, for $\beta > 0$, there are solutions when $(2n - 1) < a < 2n$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, what happens when $a \rightarrow n$?

If $-1 < n$ then

$$
\lim_{a \rightarrow n} \bigl(\beta^{-a} \Gamma(a) \sin(a \pi) + 
 e^\beta \beta^{2 a - 1} \Gamma(1 - a) \sin(a \pi)\bigl) = \frac{\pi}{(n-1)!} \beta^{2n-1}e^\beta,
$$
so $\beta$ should be equal to zero, but then, in order to apply the implicit function theorem, the limits in the reverse order should exist, which is not the case.

If $n < -1$ the analog argument applies.

Now, if $\beta < 0$, the condition that $a \in \mathbb{R}$ implies that there is no solution at all.

Whit all this in mind, the implicit function theorem will guaranty that $a  =a(\beta)$ as long as

$$
\partial_a \left\{\frac{\pi}{\Gamma^2(a)\sin (\pi a)}e^\beta \beta^{3a-1} \right\}\neq 0
$$

and $\beta = \beta(a)$ if we take $\partial_\beta\{\}$ instead. With a bit more of effort, one can show that the `ContourPlot`shown by Mark is qualitatively correct (not that it wasn't in the first place, but since the original expression is so obscure, it's hard to see -at least for me- if there aren't any artifacts behind the plot), and continue to work with confidence.